# xdelta3 fails to decode on block device

Tags: upgrade, block-device, patch, buffer

I'm trying to use `xdelta3` to bring a remote block device into sync with a local one. I'm able to easily generate a `xdelta3` patch file using the command:

```
xdelta3 -e -B 33554432 -v -9 -I 0 -s /dev/loop5p2 /dev/loop4p2 patch.xd3
```

However, when I try to decode on the remote system using the following command:

```
 xdelta3 -v -d -B 33554432 -s /dev/sda2 patch.xd3 /dev/sda3
```

…I get the following error:

```
xdelta3: non-seekable source in decode: XD3_INTERNAL
```

As I understand it, this is caused by not having a large enough buffer. However, my `-B` argument is equal to the creator of the patch. In fact, I can double that size and it still won't work.